# How to remote deploy the K2 package to K2 Server?

Tags: deployment, msbuild, teamcity, k2

I am working on a K2 project and use the TeamCity as Continuous Integration tool. I built a code to get the K2 project and create K2 deployment package, it is working fine. When I try to run the MSBuild to deploy the K2 deployment package to K2 server.

```
msbuild "DeploymentPackage\Workflow.msbuild" /p:TestOnly=True /p:Environment=Development
```

I got below error information:

```
[SourceCode.DeploymentTasks.ExportProcessTask] Deploy Process: Task Error: Connection string has not been initialized. Connection to Host Server cannot be established.
```

I run the MSBuild on K2 server is ok, I want to know how to run the MSBuild and deploy the K2 deployment package from other server (TeamCity Server)? how to setup the MSBuild parameter and which type user authority is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the Host value in your K2 connection strings for the target environment in the generated MSBuild file.  For example:

```
<Field Name="Workflow Management Server" Value="Integrated=True;IsPrimaryLogin=True;Authenticate=True;EncryptedPassword=False;Host=dlx;Port=5555" />
```

Keep in mind that is just one of many that may need to be changed.  I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution

You have to import K2 SourceCode Snapin in PowerShell, once imported you can call K2 deploy package command to install K2 package via PowerShell.

You can configure Team City's build step to call PowerShell command which will install the K2 package. I hope this helps you.